# ANR effect when using Volley

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-volley, bottomnavigationview, android-anr-dialog

I've been trying to solve this problem for two days. Unfortunately, the improvements are minimal.

I'm using BottomNavigationView, which switches fragments using `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(...`

Each fragment, when created, calls the API using Volley. example:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_services, container, false);

        ....

        callAPI();
}
```

```
private void callAPI() {
        VolleyUtils.makeJsonObjectRequest(context, ..., new VolleyResponseListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(String message) {
                  System.out.println("Error: " + message);
            }
            
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                  //JSON processing
                  //textView.setText(...);
            }
        }
}
```

VolleyUtils.java:

```
public class VolleyUtils {

    public static void makeJsonObjectRequest(Context context, ..., final VolleyResponseListener listener) {
        StringRequest jsonObjectRequest = new StringRequest
                (Request.Method.POST, "API URL", listener::onResponse, error -> listener.onError(error.toString())) {

            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                //DATA
            }

            @Override
            protected Response<String> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                try {
                    String jsonString = new String(response.data,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                    JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                    jsonString = responseObj.getJSONObject("response").toString();
                    //System.out.println(jsonString); //TODO remove debug line
                    return Response.success(jsonString,
                            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException | JSONException e) {
                    return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
                }
            }
        };

        // Access the RequestQueue through singleton class.
        VolleySingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

VolleySingleton.java:

```
public class VolleySingleton {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static VolleySingleton instance;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    private static Context ctx;

    private VolleySingleton(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized VolleySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new VolleySingleton(context);
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null)
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

VolleyResponseListener:

```
public interface VolleyResponseListener {
    void onError(String message);

    void onResponse(String response);
}
```

The problem is that an ANR effect occurs when switching fragments using BottomNavigationView

The best improvements I managed to achieve this through:

```
APIRunnable apiRunnable = new APIRunnable();
thread = new Thread(apiRunnable);
thread.start();

...

class APIRunnable implements Runnable {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callAPI();
        }
    }
```

But with faster switching, the ANR effect still occurs

`I/Choreographer: Skipped 64 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`

I really don't know how to solve it anymore. I will be happy for any help

Thank you

Comment: I'd highly recommend migrating to Retrofit from Volley. You will save yourself a lot of the headaches you're currently having

Comment: @IvanWooll ok, lemme try

Comment: @IvanWooll it is worse :(

Comment: @IvanWooll Now ANR also occurs in the emulator, which did not happen before

Answer (score 0):

**I solved the problem:**

I didn't realize that when I requested the API, I called a method that generated POST data.

I now call this method with `new Thread` and then call the API.

This solved the problem, and even with fast switching, everything is smooth.

However, I also switched from Volley to Retrofit.

Thanks to Ivan for his help